# MySQL query slows down computer

Tags: mysql

I am running a query to my MySQL database. The query takes up to 5min:

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as tasks,
  tasks.owner,
  ROUND(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, tasks.created_on, tasks.last_modified)), 0) as avg_time
FROM
  tasks 
LEFT JOIN
  objects ON objects.number = tasks.relationship
WHERE
  tasks.status != "Potential"
GROUP BY
  tasks.owner
ORDER BY avg_time DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The `tasks` table has about 60,000 rows.
The `mysqld` process of my MacBook Pro takes the entire CPU and my fans turn up. Is my query bad or are 60,000 rows to much for MySQL?
The `objects` table, that I'm joining has about 15,000 rows.

Here are the create statements:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `complete` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `completed_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delegate` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `task_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `reassigned` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `relationship` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unique_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=59444 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `objects` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `context` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `route` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `relationship` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unique_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `proposed_solution` text,
  `region_of_approval` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `requested_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `promotion_state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `business` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `number` (`number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16700 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here is some sample data for `objects`:

```
"id","name","number","context","owner","route","created_on","last_modified","status","project","relationship","unique_id","type","description","proposed_solution","region_of_approval","requested_by","customer","promotion_state","priority","business"
1,"NEW ARTICLE","CN0345928","Library","Max","Change Released","2020-11-17 06:13:00","2020-11-17 06:13:00","Released",NULL,"CR86030","2516967988","Change Notice","",NULL,"Americas-Europe",NULL,"","Released",NULL,"EU"
2,"Set Hose to Service Only","CN0345931","Library","Mo","Set to Service Only","2020-11-17 06:37:00","2020-11-17 06:37:00","Released",NULL,"CR86171","2516984806","Change Notice","",NULL,"Americas-Europe",NULL,"","Service Only",NULL,"EU"
3,"NEW MEASURING DEVICE","CN0344110","Library","Max","Promote to Release","2020-10-19 08:24:00","2020-10-19 08:39:00","Released",NULL,"CR85808","2493544772","Change Notice","",NULL,"Europe",NULL,"","Released",NULL,"EU"
```

and for `tasks`:

```
"id","complete","completed_by","owner","delegate","created_on","task_name","last_modified","reassigned","role","status","relationship","unique_id"
1,"No","member",NULL,"","2008-08-27 20:28:00","Test of creating a parent part","2008-08-27 20:28:00","No","Assignee","Potential",11377,"3A67054501"
2,"Yes","member",NULL,"","2008-09-02 16:02:00","create a bom","2008-09-02 16:11:00","No","Assignee","Completed",11496,"3A67490902"
3,"Yes","member",NULL,"","2008-09-02 16:12:00","create a bom","2008-09-02 16:17:00","No","Reviewer","Completed",11496,"3A67491252"
```

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE for both tables.

Comment: The numbers are tiny for mysql. Please add your table definitions(we need to see what indexes are in place) and an execution plan.

Comment: Is `tasks.relationship` indexed? If so, is `objects.number` a foreign key to that index?

Comment: @Cid none of that is the case. I added the create statements

Comment: It seems an odd design and an odd query and I cannot visualise the data can you add sample data from both tables as text to the question.

Comment: I added the required data

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` tell you about the query performance?

Comment: the styles of objects.number and tasks.relationship are not the same , I don't know whether that;s because of the sample data you picked or because that's the way it is and your query on the sample data does not find anything from objects.

Comment: that come from the CSV export. Both are VARCHAR

Comment: When I said style I meant tasks.relationship looks like a number and objects.number starts CN.

Comment: Within that thousands of rows there are different kind of number pattern

Comment: besides my other answer here on that page: you need an index on the "relationship" column of tasks. your statement will compare these columns on a varchar basis. that is very slow. you need integers to compare faster. 

an index will create hashes for every string in your "relationship" column and turn your search into an integer search :) on that column - simple said. 

Be Aware .. Insert and Update will be slower because the new index has to be created too.. just keep that in mind if you deal with 60.000 inserts

Comment: Indexing was the issue and thanks for the hint with the inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the WHERE condition into the LEFT JOIN.
Do you really need a LEFT JOIN? Cant you use an INNER JOIN here?

```
INNER JOIN objects ON objects.number = tasks.relationship AND tasks.status <> 'Potential'
```

60.000 or 15.000 entities is nothing for a database :) like MySQL/MariaDB. Databases use Indizes to improve lookups significantly but you have to identitfy and create an index.

If you have performance issues:

1. Try to decrease the amount of rows that are joined (dont just JOIN left .. sometimes it could be better to start with the tasks and join the objects. use inner join when it is possible)
2. use the task condition earlier and decrease the rows before you join them
3. Make a Stored Procedure from your statement (Server can execute it faster)
4. Use indizes on the important fields of your search

Comment: Thinking about going from left to inner makes sense. What is the exact difference between hafting the WHERE condition as a WHERE condition to including it to the join?

Comment: in my understanding it will filter the tasks *before* applying the Functions inside the Select while the WHERE clause will filter them *after* these functions where executed for every group

Comment: The 4. point solved the issue. But all the rest is very helpful as well. Thank you